# Fetch release information from Google Play Console API

Tags: discord, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

As the title already says, I want to get the release information of an app in the google play store whenever a new release is published.
I want to combine it with a discord bot and create a javascript script that sends the release information to my server, whenever I publish an update for my app.
Is this possible and if yes, how would I fetch the data? Which API would I have to use?

I´ve already looked around in the internet, but I didn´t found out what API i have to use or how to start at all.